# openpyxl for Conditioned Formatting of an Excel File

Tags: python, openpyxl

Brand new to openpyxl and the program abstraction of what I am writing is this: There is a list of street names in Excel. The user should be able to input: a street name to search for in one column, a string to input in a separate column, and which column the string should be input to. If a match with `street` is found in column A, `day` is inserted in the adjacent cell in column `add_to_col`.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Necessary imports for xlsx files
import openpyxl as xl

#Import file
wb = xl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

#Initialize values for openpyxl use
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

#Accept user input
street = input("Street name: ")
day = input("Day to append: ")
add_to_col = int(input("Column to add value to: "))

#Initialize values for loop use
row = 2
column = add_to_col
mycell = sheet['A2']

#Iterate through column and return corresponding day in adjacent row
for i in range(row,6300):
    
    if mycell.value == street:
        cellref = sheet.cell(row=i, column=column)
        mycell.value == day

#Save workbook
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

From my understanding, openpyxl reads columns as characters rather than ints, so I'm running into a type error when `cellref = sheet.cell(row=i, column=column)` is executed.

How can I implement this for either A. openpyxl to recognize columns as characters or B. take a different approach to add values to an adjacent cell when a match for street is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always referenced cells by the column number as below:

```
ws.cell(row=10,column=3).value =
```

But remember, column indexes are 0 based.

Comment: Beautiful. This is a much better way to reference cells than I was trying to do.

Ended up getting it to work using an iterative i variable in the row parameter and assigning proper input values to the cell in the adjacent column. Thanks.